# Animation Problem on Selection Sort Algorithm Simulation using jQuery and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to visualize the selection sort algorithm. The movements start working properly and the array elements reverse, but suddenly, for the last iterations, everything turns into a mess as shown in the picture. I can't figure out the problem.

```
async function selectionSort(main_arr) {

    for (var i=0; i<main_arr.length; i++)
    {   
        var min_ind=i;
        for(var j=i+1; j<main_arr.length; j++)
        {
            if(main_arr[min_ind]>main_arr[j])
            {
                min_ind=j;
            }
        }
        if(min_ind!=i)
        {
            var temp=main_arr[min_ind];
            main_arr[min_ind]=main_arr[i];
            main_arr[i]=temp;
            var offbig=$('.slot'+min_ind).offset().left,offsmall=$('.slot'+i).offset().left;
            
            $(".slot"+min_ind).animate(
                {
                    right:offbig-offsmall
                }
            ,500);
            
            $(".slot"+i).animate(
                {
                    left:offbig-offsmall
                }
            ,500);
            
            await sleep(1000);
        }
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is although you have mutated the array itself, you have not considered the class as well. You utilize the class `.slotX` where X is its index on the array. You need to mutate the class as well. You can do this on the callback of `animation` so that after the animation, you will have the correct "order" of the sorted array in your CSS classes.

Lastly, I do not recommend using CSS properties `left` and `right` simultenously in this scenario.

> When both left and right are defined, if not prevented from doing so
> by other properties, the element will stretch to satisfy both. If the
> element cannot stretch to satisfy both -- for example, if a width is
> declared -- the position of the element is over-constrained. When this
> is the case, the left value has precedence when the container is
> left-to-right; the right value has precedence when the container is
> right-to-left.

You can read more at [CSS Left](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left) & [CSS Right](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/right).

You can simply continue using `left` property to move your containers around. In this case, I mutate their new `left` property relative to it's current position.

```
async function selectionSort(main_arr) {

    for (var i=0; i<main_arr.length; i++)
    {   
        var min_ind=i;
        for(var j=i+1; j<main_arr.length; j++)
        {
            if(main_arr[min_ind]>main_arr[j])
            {
                min_ind=j;
            }
        }
        if(min_ind!=i)
        {
            var temp=main_arr[min_ind];
            main_arr[min_ind]=main_arr[i];
            main_arr[i]=temp;
            
            var offbig = $('.slot'+min_ind).offset().left
            var offsmall = $('.slot'+i).offset().left 
            
            $(".slot"+min_ind).animate(
                {
                    left:parseFloat($(".slot"+min_ind).css("left").replace("px", "")) - (offbig-offsmall)
                }
            ,500);
            
            $(".slot"+i).animate(
                {
                    left:parseFloat($(".slot"+i).css("left").replace("px", "")) + (offbig-offsmall)
                }
            ,500, function(){
                $('.slot'+i).removeClass('slot'+i).addClass('slot'+min_ind).addClass('temp');
                $('.slot'+min_ind).not('.temp').removeClass('slot'+min_ind).addClass('slot'+i);
                $('.temp').removeClass('temp');
            });
            
            await sleep(1000);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Take note that the logic for these lines `left:parseFloat($(".slot"+min_ind).css("left").replace("px", "")) -/+ (offbig-offsmall` are specific for the Selection Sort Algo. The index i will *always* move right & the min index will always move *left*